# Android: Copy and paste of an image do not work!

Tags: android, image

I want to copy a picture from asstets folder and paste it in my package, just for test. but final image doesn't show anything. when I want to open picture with paint, it says that "This is not a valid bitmap file".

In my program, I start to read original image in this way:

```
private void copyImage()
{
    AssetManager am = getResources().getAssets();               
    try{
        image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(am.open("tasnim.png"));
        imWidth  = image.getWidth();
        imHeight = image.getHeight();
    } 
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error accoured!");
    }
}
```

next, I'll get pixels of image or extract pixels, and save pixels in array of integer (rgbstream).

```
private void getPixelsOfImage()
{
    rgbStream = new int[imWidth * imHeight];
    image.getPixels(rgbStream, 0, imWidth, 0, 0, imWidth, imHeight);
}
```

finally, I want to save it in my package,

```
private void createPicture()
{
    contextPath = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
    String path = contextPath + "/" + picName;

    try{
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos); 

        for(int i=0; i<rgbStream.length; i++)
            dos.writeByte(rgbStream[i]);

        dos.flush();
        dos.close();
        fos.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("IOException : " + e);
    }
    System.out.println("Picture Created.");
}
```

Code works fine but result, nothing!!! :( 
When I check DDMS it creates new file and store all pixels (because it shows the size of this file is 13300 and dimension of my original picture is 100*133). when I click "pull a file from the device" I can save it on my desktop. However, when I open it :) nothing.

What you think? is there any problem in my code? 
Thanks

Comment: I'm almost positive that's not the way pngs work.

Comment: Can you explain what "nothing" means? Is there a file? How big is it? What are the contents when you look at a hex dump? How are you opening it?

Comment: @Falmarri: Are those supposed to be PNG files? Looks like the code is trying to write out a raw image file.

Comment: Can someone with more rep please change "a image" to "an image", it's making my skin crawl.

Comment: @Coltin - done. I feel your pain!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your intent is - do you want to write out a raw image file?

Assuming that you want to write a JPEG or PNG or whatever, you can erase your entire code and do something a lot easier:

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(am.open("tasnim.png"));
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
```

With proper error checking of course.

Comment: Thanks dear EboMike, actually, my intent is to extract pixels of a PNG picture, then manipulate pixels (for steganography) and then save this new picture. I wrote this code but it didn't work. to find where is my problem I'm doing above code to find my problem. So, my final picture should be as same as original picture without any changes in capacity, dimention and size. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to help, Hesam! My approach should do the trick. There are lots of ways to modify a Bitmap (without having to first get the pixels), so this approach should be perfect for you. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks again EboMike, it seems that Bitmap.PNG has problem. I did several things but I couldn't resolve it. is it possible to check it. thanks again.

Comment: Try `Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG`. "Problem" means it didn't compile?